# ¿Pudiera o pueda?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, subjuntivo, tiempos-pasados

En un contexto formal, llámese *profesor - alumno* por ejemplo, ¿qué palabra es más acorde para dirigirse a una autoridad?

Ejemplo:

> Estimado profesor,
>
> > Junto con saludar, me dirijo a usted con
> >     intención, de confirmar de mi parte la asistencia, en caso de haber algún problema por favor, 
> >     pudiera comunicarme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ninguna de las dos funciona en ese ejemplo. Se puede usar *podría* si se cambia la oración a interrogativa:

> En caso de haber algún problema, ¿podría comunicármelo?

Sin embargo, en determinados casos una pregunta directa por escrito puede no ser suficientemente formal. Dos opciones para escribir el ejemplo de manera más formal son:

> Junto con saludar, me dirijo a usted con intención de confirmar de mi parte la asistencia. En caso de haber algún problem, por favor, le agradecería que me lo comunicase.
>
> Junto con saludar, me dirijo a usted con intención de confirmar de mi parte la asistencia. En caso de haber algún problema, por favor no dude en comunicármelo.

Comment: "una pregunta directa por escrito puede no ser suficientemente formal" -- muy bien explicado.  Propongo: *Junto con saludar, me dirijo a usted con intención, de confirmar de mi parte la asistencia y, en caso de presentarse cualquier problema, la voluntad de tratar de resolverlo, si se me hiciera el favor de comunicarmelo.*  No sé si esto funciona -- estas comunicaciones indirectas no concuerdan muy bien con mi carácter.